# Using custom method names in Eloquents "One to many" relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

I have 2 tables with simple `one to many` relation.

users table:

```
id (primary key)
-- other columns ...
```

posts table:

```
id (primary key)
user_id
-- other columns ...
```

In User model I have:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function postsbla() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
}
```

In Post model I have:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Post extends Model
{
    public function userbla() {
        return $this->belongsTo( "App\User",'user_id', 'id' );
    }
}
```

Then, one of my controller I have:

```
use App\User;
use App\Post;


public function index()
{
    $a = true;
    if($a) { // case 1
        $user_id = 1;
        $user_posts = User::find( $user_id )->postsbla;
        var_dump($user_posts); exit;
    }
    else { // case 2
        $post_id = 5;
        $post_owner_user_data = Post::find( $post_id )->usersbla;
        var_dump($post_owner_user_data); exit;
    }
}
```

if `$a === true` (case 1) then custom method name `postsbla()` works and var_dump returns valid object, but if `$a === false`,  (case 2) then custom method name `usersbla()` not works and returns NULL.

P.S.
if I use not `usersbla` name, but `user` instead, then case 2 works too and gives valid object.

Please tell me, why can I use custom method name for case 1, and can't use for case 2 ?

Comment: can you give your tables picture?????

Comment: by the way, laravel has function `dd($someData)` to dump data and die. use it instead of `var_dump($someData); exit;`

Comment: do you have `user` relation in your post model?

Comment: @RomanBobrik   - Yes, I have, like this: `public function usersbla() {
    return $this->belongsTo( "App\User" );
}`

Comment: no, i mean exactly `user()` reation, which gives you right data. or is it magic method?

Comment: @RomanBobrik - If I use method with exactly name `user()`, then relation works, can I not use custom method name?

Comment: I thought relation is defined by parameter `"App\User"` and not methods   name itself . I'm wrong ?

Comment: @TanvirAhmed - There is no problem with tables, tables are defined as I wrote in post. the problem is naming of methods, so if I use `user` as method name, instead of `usersbla`, then relation works.

Comment: @OTAR maybe you tried that with explicitly specified foreignkey and users primary key `return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');`

Comment: I would suggest posting the content of you `App\Post` and `App\User` models, it will make it easier to understand. `user()` is not a magic method for a model as far as i'm aware

Comment: @Spholt - I added full code for both models.

Comment: @konstantinkoslow - Yes, passing second parameter `user_id` solves problem, but why this is neccessary i don't get, I thought foreignkey name is defined by first parameter `App\User`. I'm wrong ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to provide the `user_id` parameter if you are following Laravel conventions on table naming. Do you have a `users` table and a `posts` table? Or have you re-named them?

Comment: @Spholt - table names are exactly `users` and `posts`. and `posts` tabel have `user_id` column.

Comment: @OTAR because in case of belongsTo, Laravel "determines the default foreign key name by examining the name of the relationship method and suffixing the method name with _id.".

Comment: @OTAR in case of hasMany "Eloquent will take the "snake case" name of the owning model and suffix it with _id."

Comment: @konstantinkoslow - O, I did not read manual as needed. Can you post Your comments as answer, so I give you credit.

Comment: @OTAR, sure. THX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you need to specify the second argument to the belongsTo method, by adding a `foreignKey`, because your method name is `userbla` and laravel says:

> Eloquent determines the default foreign key name by examining the name of the relationship method and suffixing the method name with `_id`.

```php
return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
```

In case of hasMany

> Eloquent will take the "snake case" name of the owning model and suffix it with _id.